# Receipt validataion nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

Here am using the receipt validation method, but it does not return the value. It returns `nil`.

```
NSData *ios7ReceiptData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL]];
        /
NSString * receiptStr = [ios7ReceiptData base64EncodedStringWithOptions: NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength];



NSDictionary *receiptDict       = [self dictionaryFromPlistData:ios7ReceiptData];


- (NSDictionary *)dictionaryFromPlistData:(NSData *)data
{


    NSError *error;
    NSDictionary *dictionaryParsed = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListWithData:data
                                                                               options:NSPropertyListImmutable
                                                                                format:nil
                                                                                 error:&error];


    if (!responseDict)
    {
        if (error)
        {
            /
        }
        return nil;
    }
    return responseDict;

}
```

But it returns the `receiptDict` as `nil`. anyone help me.
How to resolve the issue?

Thanks advance

Comment: You need to initialize dictionary in order to assign value to it.
 NSDictionary *receiptDict  = [[NSDictionary alloc]init];
 receiptDict = [self dictionaryFromPlistData:ios7ReceiptData];

Comment: my problem is transaction.transactionReceipt  contains the purchase-Info but [[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL]] does not contain the purchase -info. how to get that?

Comment: The dictionaryFromPlistData: method returns proper NSDictionary object for data returned by transactionReceipt, but it returns nil using data returned using appStoreReceiptURL -- and consequetly I don't get valid receipt!